# Python, Sqlite s near "[i]": syntax error error

Tags: python, syntax

B3ticker is a list

```
for i in range(0,len(B3tickers())):
    cur.execute( 'create table simbolo[i] '\
'(data datetime primary key, '\
'open REAL, '\
'high REAL, '\
'low REAL, '\
'close REAL, '\
'adjclose REAL)')
```

Comment: It’s invalid SQL. You probably mean to _interpolate_ the value of `i` into the string used as SQL. Although, that is a _horrid_ way to structure SQL generally.. consider if the PK is (symbol, date) as trivial alternative scheme, which also entirely mitigates this ask/issue.

Comment: So what can I do? B3tickers is a list of stocks, and I want to create a table for each stock. Can I do that on Sqlite3? I'm actually new in SQL

Comment: “You probably mean to _**interpolate**_ the value of `i` into the string used as SQL.” That’s a useful keyword that’s been emphasized — see https://www.google.com/search?q=python+interpolate+string which should show what is meant, and how such will _change the value given to SQL_ for the table name. The SQL cannot magically ‘see’ Python variables, not does it flow the same rules.

Comment: Oh thanks, I understand. I did a search but I'm not fully understanding the way I should do it. so i.e, if I have a list like B3tickers() = [APPL, GOOGL, FB], how could I interpolate then?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ ,  https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation , https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/ - replace `cur.execute` with `print` to primitively verify the text _actually_ used as SQL. Using a separate string variable will also likely lead to cleaner code.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own Answer). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer). However, be sure your question contains enough information so it's possible for anyone to be able to determine your Answer actually is the solution (i.e. not just because you say it is).